# How to add className to Ant Design Mobile Dialog footer button?

Tags: reactjs

I am using Ant Design Mobile React.
And I am trying add className to Modal footer button.

This is what I tried so far, but this is not adding className.

```
<Modal
          visible={this.state.modal1}
          transparent
          maskClosable={false}
          onClose={this.onClose('modal1')}
          title="Title"
          footer={[{ text: 'Ok', className:'btn-ok', onPress: () => { console.log('ok'); this.onClose('modal1')(); } }]}
          wrapProps={{ onTouchStart: this.onWrapTouchStart }}
          afterClose={() => { alert('afterClose'); }}
        >
```

Answer (score 0):

The prop footer takes in a react node. So it should be this:

```
          footer={<button className="btn-ok">Ok</button>}
```

Comment: <Modal
          visible={this.state.modal1}
          transparent
          maskClosable={false}
          onClose={this.onClose('modal1')}
          title="Title"
          footer={<button className="btn-ok">Ok</button>}
          wrapProps={{ onTouchStart: this.onWrapTouchStart }}
          afterClose={() => { alert('afterClose'); }}
        >   Do you mean this ?

Comment: @user1833620 Yes that should work. According to the documentation for Ant Design. If you want I can open a code sandbox